# Second derivation equation with mean-value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^2$. Let $Q=[a,a+h]\times[b,b+k]$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define $$\lambda(h,k)=f(a,b)-f(a+h,b)-f(a,b+k)+f(a+h,b+k).$$ Then there is a point $\textbf{p}$ of $Q$ such that $\lambda(h,k)=D_2D_1f(\textbf{p})\cdot hk$.

The proof of this uses two applications of the mean-value theorem.

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^2$. Prove that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(a+t)-2g(a)+g(a+t)}{t^2}=g''(a).$$ [Hint: Consider the above with $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$.]

Following the hint, I define $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$, substitute $a$ and $b$ with $\dfrac{a-h}{2}$, and $h$ and $k$ with $h$. So I have that there exists a point $\textbf{p}$ of $\left[\dfrac{a-h}{2},\dfrac{a+h}{2}\right]\times\left[\dfrac{a-h}{2},\dfrac{a+h}{2}\right]$ such that $$g(a-h)-2g(a)+g(a+h)=D_2D_1g(x(\textbf{p})+y(\textbf{p}))\cdot h^2$$

This looks close to what I need, but I'm quite confused about

1) How to prove that $f$ is of class $C^2$

2) How to interpret $D_2D_1g(x(\textbf{p})+y(\textbf{p}))$. Can I just say that $x(\textbf{p})+y(\textbf{p})\in[a-h,a+h]$, and so $D_2D_1g(x(\textbf{p})+y(\textbf{p})) = g''(z)$ for some $z\in[a-h,a+h]$?

3) If I can solve the problem in 2), I would get that for every $h$, there exists $z\in[a-h,a+h]$ such that $\dfrac{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)}{h^2}=g''(z)$. How can I reach the conclusion from here?

Comment: I could've sworn the second question has been asked before last week

Comment: @sidht It might have been. The point here is to prove it using the first question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) This is just the chain rule.

(ii) We have $$D_2D_1\> g(x+y)=D_2\> g'(x+y)=g''(x+y)$$
for all $(x,y)$ in question. Therefore
$$D_2D_1\> g\bigl(x({\bf p}+y({\bf p})\bigr)=g''(z)\ ,$$
where
$$z:=x({\bf p})+y({\bf p})\in[a-h,a+h]\ .$$
(iii) This means that for any $h>0$ there is a $z_h\in[a-h,a+h]$ such that
$$g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)=g''(z_h)\> h^2\ ,$$
or
$${g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)\over h^2}=g''(z_h)\ .$$
Letting $h\to0+$ one obtains
$$\lim_{h\to0+}{g(a+h)-2g(a)+g(a-h)\over h^2}=g''(a)$$
by continuity of $g''$.

By the way, the claim immediately follows from Taylor's theorem in the form
$$g(a\pm h)=g(a)\pm h g'(a)+{h^2\over2} g''(a)+o(h^2)\qquad(h\to0)\ .$$